# Displaying the axes on mirror barplot in (basic) R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, axis

Sorry if the question is quite naive but I am stuck and could not find a specific answer elsewhere. I am a beginner. I cannot make the vertical axis show in the plot explained below.

```
barplot(-(seq(0,10,2)), width=0.6, space=1, xlim=c(-12,12), ylim=c(2,10), horiz=T, axisnames=FALSE,col="green")
barplot(seq(0,10,2),add=T, width=0.6, space=1, axes=F,horiz=T,axisnames=FALSE,col="darkred")
```

When I try to "include the option axis.lty=1 to draw it" (quoted from statmethods.net) I get warning saying it is "no graphical parameter". Please could anyone enlighten me in using boxplot() to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the manual of `barplot`:

> axisnames  logical. If TRUE, and if there are names.arg (see above),
>   the other axis is drawn (with lty = 0) and labeled.
>
> axis.lty   the graphics parameter lty applied to the axis and tick
>   marks of the categorical (default horizontal) axis. Note that by
>   default the axis is suppressed.

That axis will be drawn only when the `height` parameter has names attributes or you supplied `names.arg`. When this criteria was satisfied, a blank axis line will be drawn, and you can make it visible with `axis.lty = 1`. See the following example (the horizontal axis overlapped the first bar because you set ylim to `c(2, 10)`):

```
barplot(
    -(seq(0,10,2)), width=0.6, space=1, names.arg = paste('h=', -(seq(0,10,2))),
    xlim=c(-12,12), ylim=c(2,10),
    horiz=T, axisnames=T,col="green", axis.lty = 1, las = 1)

barplot(seq(0,10,2),add=T, width=0.6, space=1,
        axes=F,horiz=T,axisnames=FALSE,col="darkred", axis.lty = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I knew it was simple but I couldn't figure it out, even in reading the manual (i.e. not used to the general jargon of the language yet). Thx much. I figure I can now use axis(2,pos=0) to relocate to plot from 0.

Comment: Oh sorry now I see axis() function generates an *independent* axis on the plot. Please, if you'd know how to move the barplot() axis to the middle 0 position, let me know here. thnx

Comment: @eduardofox, you can do it with `axis(2, pos = 0)`, see `?axis` for detail.